# Date difference does not output correctly

Tags: php

I have the following code to find difference between two dates in days, hours and minutes:

```
    $date1=date_create("2019-01-01");
    $date2=date_create("2019-02-01");
    $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
    echo $diff->format("%d day, %h hour, %i minute");
    exit;
```

But when I run this code I am getting this unexpected output:

```
0 day, 0 hour, 0 minute
```

Does anybody have idea what is that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%d` format specification prints the number of days difference between the day of the month, which in your case is 0. If you were to print the months difference (using `%m`) you would see it is 1. If you want the total number of days, you need to use `%a` instead i.e.

```
echo $diff->format("%a day, %h hour, %i minute");
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Jthde)